# List menu by Parse XML in J2ME

Tags: java-me, kxml

I want to create menu from XMLFile. My xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<parent title="Layanan Anda">
    <menu title="Info Kartu">
        <submenu title="Informasi Saldo">
            <input type="numberpassword" length="4">Kode </input>
        </submenu>
        <submenu title="Mutasi Kartu Utama">
            <input type="numberpassword" length="4">Kode </input>
        </submenu>
        <submenu title="Mutasi Kartu Lain">
            <input type="number" length="10">Kartu</input>
            <input type="numberpassword" length="4">Kode </input>
        </submenu>
        <submenu title="Deposito">
            <input type="number" length="10">Bilyet</input>
            <input type="numberpassword" length="4">Kode </input>
        </submenu>
    </menu>
    <menu title="Kartu Anda">
    </menu>
    <menu title="Other Info">
    </menu>
    <menu title="Isi">
    </menu>
</parent>
<parent title="Menu Favorit">
</parent>
<parent title="Recent Menu">
</parent>
<parent title="Setting">
</parent>    
</root>
```

In HomeScreen, list menu parent will show first. And when I click parent menu, application will show list menu from "menu" tag. When I click menu again, application will show list menu from submenu. And vice versa when I want to back to parent menu.

How can I implement this in J2ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse your XML file and create a tree structure to hold the menu/submenu items. Each node should hold the items of a single level. For example:

- root: Layanan Anda, Menu Favorit, Recent Menu, Setting

  - menu: Info Kartu, Kartu Anda, Other Info, Isi

    - submenu: Informasi Saldo, Mutasi Kartu Utama, Mutasi Kartu Lain, Deposito

Then use a graphical List to show the items of a node.

Comment: xml structure can not be changed.

Comment: You do not have to change the xml structure to implement what I said.

Comment: sorry if I'm slow to understand, do you have some tutorial on link?
In this case, when I click menu 'Info Kartu', application will show list menu from it's sub menu. Likewise when I click menu 'Kartu Anda', application will show list menu from it's sub menu, and so on

Comment: do you mean like this http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_parse_an_XML_file_in_Java_ME_with_kXML ?